# XSalsa20 + Poly1305 authentication wtihout tag

Tags: authenticated-encryption, poly1305, xsalsa20

Do I understand correctly that XSalsa20 + Poly1305 provides authentication without a tag? If so, then how does that work?

I came to that conclusion by reading http://nacl.cr.yp.to/secretbox.html, "Secret-key authenticated encryption", where it states (as far as I understand) that the ciphertext has the same length as the plaintext.

Comment: Where did you see that it has no tag for authentication? The Poly1305 is producing the authentication tag.

Comment: @kelalaka I think its the wording here  " The crypto_secretbox function puts the ciphertext into c[0], c[1], ..., c[mlen-1]. It then returns 0"

Comment: @ModalNest The doc misleading see https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah agree re the doc. OP you can find an online demo of secretbox [here](https://tweetnacl.js.org/#/secretbox).

Comment: @ModalNest, I think what he means is that the message needs to be padded with 32 bytes of zeroes, and that message will be encrypted into ciphertext, out of which the first 16 bytes will be zero, therefore the following 16 are likely the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a bit misleading about `crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305` that uses a 16-byte authentication tag of [poly1305](https://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf). The [libsodium](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox) has more clear explanation on it. From [Bernstein' paper's abstract](https://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf);

> Poly1305-AES computes a 16-byte authenticator of a variable-length message, using a 16-byte AES key, a 16-byte additional key, and a 16-byte nonce

I would be surprised that one authenticates an arbitrary message without using a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) tag (Wikipedia quote);

> In cryptography, a message authentication code (MAC), sometimes known as a tag, is a short piece of information used to authenticate a message—in other words, to confirm that the message came from the stated sender (its authenticity) and has not been changed.

Therefore the short piece of information must be somewhere!.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. Indeed, I find DJB's software a bit confusing.

Comment: Reading from multiple sources, if exists, can enlighten.